# Python single plot in a for loop without creating a list or array

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, matplotlib, plot

This may sound like a very naive question. However, to me, it's quite fundamental: Can python plot variables without putting them into arrays or lists? I couldn't find much answer on the net or SO and please let me know if there's any duplicate.

I have the following code for demonstration:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = 0.0
dx = 0.5

for i in range(10):
    y = x**2
    plt.plot(x,y)
    x += dx

plt.show()


x = np.linspace(-0,.5,10)
y = x**2
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The first part doesn't plot (which is in an explicit for-loop) anything while the second part does (where both `x` and `y` are numpy arrays).

Is it possible to plot without storing variables in arrays or lists?  `plt.scatter(x,y,c='r')` works but that doesn't produce any line plot.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid using arrays or lists?  Plotting implies that you have a bunch of data points, and trying to manage a bunch of data points without some kind of collection (e.g. an array or list) sounds like one of the lower circles of hell.  You *could* write a plotting library that doesn't allow the caller to use lists, but nobody would want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Store the start and end of each segment to iteratively build a series of lines from datapoint to datapoint: `(x0,y0)` -> `(x1, y1)`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x0, y0 = 0, 0
x1 = 0.0
dx = 0.5

for i in range(10):
    y1 = x1**2
    plt.plot([x0,x1],[y0,y1], 'o-')
    x0, y0 = x1, y1
    x1 += dx

plt.show()
```

[image: Lineplot]

Note: this example will draw a line from `(0,0)` to `(0,0)` as the `x1` value chosen is starting at `0.0`